# Problem displaying barButtonItem for popoverController in detailView

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

I have a splitViewContller with detailView, which is a NavigationController and delegate for SplitView.
In this NavigationController, I store the "barButtonItem" and "popoverController" arguments, that I get from the method:

```
splitViewController:willHideViewController:withBarButtonItem:forPopoverController:
```

like this:

```
self.barButtonItemVsebine = barButtonItem;
self.popoverController = pc;
```

Then, I want to display the "barButtonItem" inside a toolbar of a view, that is loaded inside the navigation view - just setting the items of toolbar:

```
[items addObject:pd.detailViewController.barButtonItemVsebine];
```

The problem is: when there are many views in the viewControllers stack of navigationController and I call popToRootViewController the "barButtonItem" doesn't show in the toolbar of the rootViewController.

I also tried to reload all buttons in the toolbar.items array every time I pop a view controller, but sometimes the button shows up, and sometimes not. All other buttons, that I create programmatically show up correctly.

Comment: Same here. Feels like iOS bug.